# Activity killed in background and ClassCastException when resumed?

Tags: android, android-activity, parcelable, onresume

This only happens after the activity has been in the background for some time. It **does not** happen if I press the "home" button and then a few seconds later reopen the app, restoring the previous state. It **does** happen when I press the"home" button and then maybe an hour later reopen the app, trying to restore the previous state.

I think the WIN DEATH is causing it. I think it's the activity being garbage collected, but I'm not sure why it doesn't just restart.

Any insights into why this is happening?

note: Game implements Parcelable

```
05-22 20:43:14.343 I/ActivityManager(401): Start proc com.example.test for activity com.example.test/.ui.MainActivity: pid=12767 uid=10117 gids={50117, 3003, 1028}
05-22 20:48:22.914 I/ActivityManager(401):                43942 kB: com.example.test (pid 12767)
05-22 20:48:22.914 I/ActivityManager(401): 12767   62632K   62488K   44006K   40068K  com.example.test
05-22 20:58:39.593 I/WindowState(401): WIN DEATH: Window{41b13370 u0 com.example.test/com.example.test.ui.MainActivity}
05-22 20:58:39.593 I/ActivityManager(401): Process com.example.test (pid 12767) has died.
05-23 11:12:25.469 I/ActivityManager(401): Start proc com.example.test for activity com.example.test/.ui.MainActivity: pid=6450 uid=10117 gids={50117, 3003, 1028}
05-23 11:12:25.696 E/AndroidRuntime(6450): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList[]
05-23 11:12:25.696 E/AndroidRuntime(6450):  at com.example.test.model.Game.(Game.java:241)
05-23 11:12:25.696 E/AndroidRuntime(6450):  at com.example.test.model.Game.(Game.java:235)
05-23 11:12:25.696 E/AndroidRuntime(6450):  at com.example.test.model.Game$1.createFromParcel(Game.java:228)
05-23 11:12:25.696 E/AndroidRuntime(6450):  at com.example.test.model.Game$1.createFromParcel(Game.java:1)
05-23 11:12:25.696 E/AndroidRuntime(6450):  at com.example.test.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:237)
05-23 11:12:25.798 W/ActivityManager(401):   Force finishing activity com.example.test/.ui.MainActivity
05-23 11:12:26.352 W/ActivityManager(401): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{4161a520 u0 com.example.test/.ui.MainActivity}
05-23 11:12:27.438 I/ActivityManager(401): Process com.example.test (pid 6450) has died.
```

Comment: neither is the GC or WIN DEATH is the cause. You have a ClassCastException. Post your code. Game.java:241

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: It's happening in `onCreate`, could you please post that routine?

Comment: I said it works, and the only time it doesn't work is right after WIN DEATH.

questions = (ArrayList<Question>[]) in.readArray(Question.class.getClassLoader());